# Linearity of electromagnetism and gravity

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, approximations, linear-systems, linearized-theory

If we have a very strong electromagnetic field, it stops being linear, Maxwell's equations stop working ($10^6$ Tesla or $10^9$ Newton/Coulomb);

Why can't we say the same thing for gravity? Since the field equations of gravity aren't linear couldn't we make the assumption at a  lower limit , they become linear?

If the energy tensor of the object is very small , the field equations become linear.

Can gravity be linear at the quantum scale while obeying GR at larger scales?

Comment: The question has been edited but I still find it quite unclear. Which is the actual problem?

Comment: [Gravity can be modeled as being linear in the Weak-Field limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity), is that what you meant? Possibly related: [In what physical situations is the weak-field limit invalid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/405685/157014)